# Change range values at once

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro that runs if a given range changes and I want to create a button that changes that range to predefined values at once so my macro also will run once

Something as: `Range("B2, B3, C2, C3").Value = (-5%; 5%; -5%; 5%)`

Comment: You possible look for something like [that](https://excelmacromastery.com/excel-vba-array/#Reading_from_a_Range_of_Cells_to_an_Array)

Comment: Edit your question and try to explain your question a bit more as this information is not enough to answer the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For rectangular area, [`Evaluate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.evaluate) can be used to make 2D array :

```
[B2:C3] = [{"-5%", "-5%"; "5%", "5%"}]   ' Excel guesses and converts to Percentage numbers
```

For columns with the same repeating values :

```
[B2:C3] = [{"-5%"; "5%"}]
```

Answer (score 2):

use this

```
Range("B2:C3").Value = Application.Transpose(Array(-0.05, 0.05))
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest you could do is to assign value to each cell separately using `Cells`:

```
Cells(2, 2).Value = "-5%" 'or -0.05 if you want numeric value
Cells(2, 3).Value = "-5%" 'or -0.05
Cells(3, 2).Value = "5%" 'or 0.05
Cells(3, 3).Value = "5%" 'or 0.05
```